# Can I use Firebase with Squarespace?

Tags: javascript, firebase, squarespace

I've built a website from the ground up already but for an upcoming one I need to use Wix or Squarespace as well as Firebase. So I set about trying to figure out if I could mesh those platforms when I came [across the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969448/can-i-store-database-information-in-squarespace) to this question:

> Can I store database information in Squarespace? A: Essentially no

Followed by this documentation from [Squarespace FAQs](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815358-Custom-code-FAQ#toc-what-code-can-i-add-to-my-site-).

[image: Squarespace FAQs on adding custom code]

I was a bit confused since Firebase uses Javascript to use Auth, Firestore, Functions etc. Even if you need to run server-side code you can make a call to Firebase via JS to run Node applications. So is it possible to use Firebase with Squarespace, if you're allowed to add custom JS to your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Firebase works fully client-side. The only backend code you write in Firebase you can deploy directly to Firebase.

You can follow the [official JavaScript web guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for Firebase to get started with this.